# What Dimensionality reduction should I choose?

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, large-data

I have dataset with 38k obsevations and 12 variables (11 binary and 1 numeric). I am interested in exploring different clustering techniques but before that which dimensionality reduction technique should be more appropriate for visualization? PCA? t-SNE? Any others?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to this site! As stated, it's hard to tell what you expect from either clustering or dimensionality reduction before multivariate data visualization. Do you want to highlight some salient aspects of the data, grouping of a subset of variables, or something else? Do you want to transform your binary or numeric variables, or to treat them separately? More details about your dataset and your objectives would likely help others to post useful recommendations.

Comment: You only have 12 dimensions, which is not large by most processes. How many are you aiming to yield and for what purpose?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It's a patient dataset and binary variables are different conditions so I am interested in understanding relationships between them. I was thinking on reduction techniques for 2 dimensions for visualization purposes and also for optimizing computation of cluster algorithms, from what I could understand from literature

Comment: If you're optimizing for computation of clustering algorithms, I don't think 12 dimensions is too bad -- in practice, for clustering, it's dataset size that is the limiting factor (i.e. pairwise distance calculations are expensive, i.e. $O(n)$, and $n^2 \gg d$ in your case.). For visualization, I honestly think that this question becomes very subjective -- it depends on what you want to show.